# OpenCV for iphone

Tags: iphone, opencv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Face Recognition on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272129/face-recognition-on-the-iphone)

I am using OpenCV for my iphone  app.
I want to  know how i can detect the face in the image and after that i want to compare it with other faces to know how is the person in the photo?
is it possible with OpenCV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible yes... But it would only work at certain angles, and would need some massive coding from your part anyway..

Also, iPhone probably would run that VERY, VERY, VERY slow! (I mean, trying to match 1 person with a database of 100 photos would probably take some hours already)

Comment: thx for your response.
i want to know the logique used to do that only to compare tow images.
There is any tuto or doc??

Comment: I do not have links now, but OpenCV has extensive documentation and samples :) I know a person that liked to call me to show the samples every time a new official one was released!

Comment: Oh, and if you liked the anwser, accept it please ^.^