# How we detect face in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone

How we detect face and compare with other face in iPhone.if it is matched it will display the user name.

Comment: use [openCV](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to go with [`CoreImage`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro/ci_intro.html).
Here are some nice tutorial & sample codes:- 
1. http://maniacdev.com/2011/11/tutorial-easy-face-detection-with-core-image-in-ios-5
2. [FaceTracker](https://github.com/aptogo/FaceTracker)
3. [FaceRecognition](https://github.com/mjp/FaceRecognition) 
Updated:- Please have a look a this. [Face Recognition on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272129/face-recognition-on-the-iphone)

Comment: its only face recognition.But i want when i save image and again take photo with same face.it will be comparison with last save image.if face is same it display alert with name how we do it.