# How can we detect face using OpenCV

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv, ios-camera

I want to build a app that keeps detecting face from the Camera. I have integrated the library but not getting any valid source from where i can start

Comment: you can check with this post http://www.appcoda.com/face-detection-core-image/

Comment: @AntonyRaphel  yup its good but i am a newbie to Swift so basically i want it in objective c

Comment: @AntonyRaphel i want to use OpenCV to achieve

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Face Recognition on the iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272129/face-recognition-on-the-iphone)

Comment: then try this one https://github.com/ekurutepe/iOS-OpenCV-FaceRec or https://github.com/macmade/FaceDetect

Comment: @AntonyRaphel i downloaded the github.com/macmade/FaceDetect and tried to configure it but i am facing issue in Xcode 8

Comment: @AntonyRaphel I have tried the link suggested by you (github.com/ekurutepe/iOS-OpenCV-FaceRec ) but the problem is the image gets converted to grey scale so how can i convert it to original image

Comment: @AhmedSahib those issues you need to raise for **iOS-OpenCV-FaceRec** library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a good starting point if you want to use Objective C:

https://jkbdev.wordpress.com/2015/09/22/getting-started-with-opencv-on-ios/

When you manage to get this to build and run, look for an opencv face detection example and incorporate that into your iOS app.

If you really want to do this in one go, you can try the link suggested by @Anthony above (https://github.com/ekurutepe/iOS-OpenCV-FaceRec).

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/ios/video_processing/video_processing.html

i already build and run and now going for the 2nd tutorial

Comment: Thanks, didn't knoe that OpenCV 3.0 comes with a good tutorial like that.

Comment: I have tried the link suggested by Anthony but the problem is the image gets converted to grey scale so how can i convert it to original image

Comment: The input to opencv face detection is a grayscale image, and the output is a set of rectangles that show face locations. You just have to draw the face rectangles on the original image, instead f the gray image.

Comment: how to face red mark and pimple detect objective c  , any know  please  let me know  , how to possible .. ?

Comment: The first approach that comes to mind is taking the HSV image of the face and looking for patches with more red. On dark skin, you will have to look for highlights.